# Android InputMethodManager with InputConnection null

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, inputmethodmanager

I am new to android in my project i have option for searching records in database. I have a EditText and a Button whenver user presses a button database will be queried for text entered by user in EditText.

It's working fine for first time after displaying the search results. For changing the search text the user wants to edit the Text in the EditText soft keyboard appearing but EditText is unresponsive with the user actions and input from the soft keyboard.

EditText is added as header to the ListView

```
    searchstringsearch=(EditText)searchview_headerview.findViewById(R.id.searchstringsearch);
    searchstringsearch.setTypeface(SharedVariables.font);
    searchstringsearch.setFilters(BLCOobj.setFilters("filterForSearchString"));
    searchstringsearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());


class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

            /*InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(HomeScreen.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchstringsearch.getWindowToken(), 0);*/
            hideKeyboard();

            String SearchOption=searchstringsearch.getText().toString();

            if(SearchOption!=null)
            {
                if(SearchOption.length()>=4)
                {


            BLHomeScreenOperations objBLHomeScreenOperations=new BLHomeScreenOperations();      
            clsSearch objSearch=new clsSearch(objdatasetslist.get(dataSetIndex).getDataSetID(),SearchOption );
            //callig getSearchResults In BL
            objBLHomeScreenOperations.getSearchResults(objSearch, HomeScreen.this);
                }else{
                    SharedVariables.showAlertMessage(SharedVariables.globalContext.getString(R.string.enter_searchstring_msg), HomeScreen.this);
                }
            }else{
                SharedVariables.showAlertMessage(SharedVariables.globalContext.getString(R.string.enter_searchstring_msg), HomeScreen.this);
            }


            return true;    
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

When the user clicks a second time for editing, the EditText log is displaying following message

```
V/InputMethodManager(16958): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@420ef980 ic=null
```

Comment: do your Searching in a seperate Thread. don't burden on EditText's OnEditorActionListener...

Comment: @GopalRao Doing the Searching in Separate Thread onlyy

Comment: If the list header containing the EditText is off-screen, the IME will fail to connect to it. Consider moving the EditText out of the ListView.